# Does the packages effect the Meteor application ?

Tags: meteor

If we have more number of packages in the Meteor Application, Is it going to effect the application speed ? (Like the server side operations and loading time).

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it just needs a little more time to load all the packages and start your app.

But if you manage your publications and subscriptions properly, and don't load unnecessary data when you don't need it, you should be good.